# How to get a String and an int vs. just a String with Scanner?

Tags: java, string, integer, java.util.scanner

I have some code that runs an addition or subtraction of two numbers based on a user's input, wherein they can either type a String followed by an integer to perform an operation, OR just a String to close the program.

My code looks like this:

```
private static int result = 0;

public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  String operation = "";
  int num = 0;
  boolean finished = false;
  
  while(!finished){
    System.out.println("Enter the operation you'd like to perform on " + result + " or type q to quit.");
    operation = kb.next();
    if(kb.hasNextInt()){ num = kb.nextInt(); } //The problem
    
    switch (operation){
      case "add":
        add(num);
        break;
      case "subtract":
        subtract(num);
        break;
      case "q":
        finished = true;
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("New result: " + result);
  }
  System.out.println("Bye!");
}

public static void add(int num){
  result += num;
} 
public static void subtract(int num){
  result -= num;
}
```

With my program, a user can input "add 3" to add 3 to result,
or "subtract 7" to subtract 7 from result, however inputting "q" only prompts the user to continue entering inputs, rather than closing the program as intended. I was hoping the `if(kb.hasNextInt())` method would detect if the user typed an integer, and only run `num = kb.nextInt()` if they did, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Typing "q" should close the program, but instead it keeps searching for an input. How can I tell my program not to look for an int after the string if there isn't one there?

I considered taking the whole input as a string and using .split() to extract the int, but that seems like a poor solution and I'm sure there must be something easier I'm not thinking of. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are your expectations?

Comment: I just want it to skip declaring num = kb.nextInt() if an int doesn't get input

Comment: NB Your `add()` and `subtract()` methods cannot possibly work. Java does not pass by reference. You need them to return a result.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post for clarity and to better reflect how the code works @user207421

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If I type `add` and then `3` it shows me a new result. If I type `add` then `subtract` then 6 it shows me another new result. It does not behave as you describe above.

Comment: In any case I can't see the point of making the number optional. If that's your way of handling 'q' without a number, there are better ways.

Comment: `hasNextInt()` is indeterminate as long as the user still *could* enter an int number, in other words, it can only return `false` if either, the stream has been closed or a non-int token has been entered. I think, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77946793/2711488) points into the right direction. After encountering `"q"`, do not even ask whether an integer follows. You may still use `hasNextInt()` to provide error feedback when the token is not an integer number. Likewise, the `switch` deserves a `default` reporting unknown commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO this is more about how you arrange the flow of your program. You may check first for 'q' (and break if yes), and proceed for arithmetic operations if not 'q'.

```
private static int result = 0;

public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  String operation = "";
  int num = 0;
  
  while(true){
    System.out.println("Enter the operation you'd like to perform on " + result + " or type q to quit.");
    operation = kb.next();
    if(operation.equals("q")) { break; }    

    switch (operation){
      case "add":
        num = kb.nextInt();
        add(num);
        break;
      case "subtract":
        num = kb.nextInt();
        subtract(num);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("New result: " + result);
  }
  System.out.println("Bye!");
}

public static void add(int num){
  result += num;
} 
public static void subtract(int num){
  result -= num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the way you get the input and store it into one single string you can split it in two by the blank space using `String.split("");`.
This will give you a string array with two parts, the first one will be the operation and the seccond one will be the number you want to add or subtract.
It is important to check the length of the string array because if you only input "*q*" you will be getting an exception.

Try using the following code and let me know if this does the work for you:

```
private static int result = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String operation[];
        int num = 0;
        boolean finished = false;

        while (!finished) {
            System.out.println("Enter the operation you'd like to perform on " + result + " or type q to quit.");
            operation = kb.nextLine().split(" ");
            
            if(operation.length == 2) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(operation[1]);
            }

            switch (operation[0]) {
            case "add":
                add(num);
                break;
            case "subtract":
                subtract(num);
                break;
            case "q":
                finished = true;
                break;
            }
            if(!finished) {
                System.out.println("New result: " + result);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }

    public static void add(int num) {
        result += num;
    }

    public static void subtract(int num) {
        result -= num;
    }
```

I have also added an if condition that checks if program is finished so when it is you don't have the result printed again.